Opening a discord invite link (intent?) within an Android WebView
I've developed a game using web technologies and I'm delivering it through an Android WebView.
On the website, I've included a hyperlink directing to my Discord server, commonly referred to as a Discord invite link.
When I open this link in my browser, everything functions correctly. However, when I attempt to click the link from my phone within the WebView app, I encounter the following error:
The webpage at intent://discordapp.page.link/?link=[....] could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

Initially, this error would appear immediately. However, after modifying my code, I've progressed slightly. Now, it directs me to the Discord view where I can accept the invitation. Nevertheless, upon clicking the 'accept' button, I encounter the same error as before.
I've attempted various solutions found online, but none have proven effective.
Instead of handling the intent, could it be feasible to open the installed browser app with the desired URL so that the browser itself can manage it rather than my app? It seems like that might be a simpler solution.
My current code looks like this:
MainActivity.java
         mywebView.setWebViewClient(new LocalContentWebViewClient(assetLoader, this) {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                final String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                if (url.contains("discord.com/invite/") || url.contains("discordapp") || url.contains("discord.gg")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

LocalContentWebViewClient simply extends WebViewClient and does some other (unrelated) stuff as well.

Hello. Have you heard of custom tabs?
Allows you to use the user's session and other functionalities.
